# How do I use a gear puller to remove a sleeve on a steering shaft without it damaging the shaft?

Tags: vw, steering, golf, tools

On my steering column (Mk1 Golf/Rabbit) there is a spline adaptor sleeve. I need to remove this. Instructions I've found say to use a gear puller for this, but when I try the puller seems to "dig" into the softer metal of the threaded shaft damaging it.

Would anyone know of a way/tricks to avoid this?

(The sleeve I am trying to remove is the part between the spring to the left and the threaded end to the right in the photo)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure how you're doing it right now to apply the puller, but the hooks of the puller should go around the back of the sleeve, between it and the spring. If this isn't working, you may need to apply heat.

Comment: Sorry @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I should have been clearer. I can get the hooks of the puller in place but the threaded "pushing" part of the puller digs into the threaded part of the shaft (just off right of the pic) damaging it. I think I'm using the puller correctly, I just need to figure out how to stop it from damaging the soft metal of the shaft.

Answer (score 1):

I take it from your comment, your puller has a point on the end without any kind of bearing, and the pointed end is digging into the shaft.

I have two things you can do.

First, you can get a puller with a bearing on the end which allows the threaded rod of the puller to turn without digging into the shaft.

Second, as long as the hooks are long enough, you can put a sacrificial nut on the end of the column, something the puller can dig into which you don't care about. Any kind of sacrificial material will work, but a nut on there will stay in place the easiest.

The other thing is, if you're just marring the inner part of the divot on the shaft, there really isn't an issue doing what you're doing. The only thing you don't want to have happen is for the end to mushroom. If damage occurs at the divot and it does not extend out into the threads, it may look ugly, but there's no issue there. The problem lies in how much is too much before you start deforming the threads.